# python manage.py startapp polls

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I'm following along with the djangoproject.com tutorial. I used pyCharm to setup a dummy project. 
on my terminal command line I cd into the folder that has manage.py i then run the line.
python manage.py startapp polls

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

What is this and why can't I create another app called polls?

Comment: Make sure you actually have Django installed on your system, and is available from within your command line.

Comment: Django is installed. What do you mean by is available from within your command line?

Comment: not sure how pyCharm works, but if Django is installed system-wide you shouldn't see that error message. Test this from your command line: python -c "import django"

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named django

Comment: Yup, seems Django isn't properly installed to be available all over your system. If you know the path where Django is installed, you can do this as a workaround: `PYTHONPATH="/path/to/django/" python manage.py <some_command>', but a proper solution would be either installing Django globally or using virtualenv if you don't want it installed globally

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I already have installed Django, but I type "runserver" command from virtualenv and it showed the same error that *Chapsterj*

I resolved typing this:

```
(venv)$ pip install Django
```

Before, To enter in virtualenv, type this:

```
$ virtualenv venv --distribute
$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv)$
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of PyCharm, but as the comments suggest, this means the python interpreter cannot find django.

One thing to try - open up a terminal (anywhere) and type:

```
python
```

then run

```
import django
```

If you have django installed, this should work; otherwise it will not.

In my case, I run all of my django installs via virtualenv (basically, localised versions of the python package index so different projects can have different versions of packages installed) so doing this from any old terminal for me doesn't work.

In my case, I then need to make an adjustment to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. Well, actually, I'm lying slightly, virtualenv is a little more complicated than that, but that's another way to make it work.

So, I would suggest:

- Making sure you have django installed in your python site-packages directory (where most third party packages live). Usually, something like `yum install python-django` or `pip install Django` will do this for you.
- If this is not where you've installed Django, edit your PYTHONPATH first in a shell session (to make it easy to test and get right) and then in your IDE so python can find it.
- If the IDE doesn't provide you with a way to edit the pythonpath variable, you should be able to manage this by editing `manage.py` like so:

  ```
  import sys
  sys.path.append('/opt/Django')

  # the rest of manage.py ...
  import django
  ```

Answer (score 1):

To properly install django you must use the "superuser", try

```
sudo pip install django
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

On Rhel6, umask prevented the django directory from being accessed, so I had to run:

```
cd /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/
find django -type d | xargs chmod 775
find django -type f | xargs chmod 664
```

and add /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/ to my path in .bash_profile.

Answer (score 0):

I see no accepted response to this and since it is not so much a Django question as it is a [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) question, I'll add my 2c in case others are having the same problem getting started.

I am also running through the "Writing your first Django" tutorial using PyCharm and I am not having these problems.  I WAS having all sorts of problems until I realized that you let PyCharm create everything and the problems go away ;-)

So far, I am reading both the PyCharm AND the Django tuts together.  PyCharm tut is here: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/creating-django-application-in-a-project.html

YOUR problem may be answered with this:

```
To add a new django application to an existing project

On the main menu, choose Tools | Run manage.py task
In the Enter manage.py task name dialog box, type startapp. Note suggestion list that appears under the dialog box after entering the first letter, and shrinks as you type to show the exact match only.
In the dialog box that opens, type the name of the new Django application.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem with PyCharm, what I did was:
Go to File -> Default Setting ->
Project Interpreter (Pick python 3...) if thats what you want to use
It will show all packages available
Double click on Django
Install Package.

Then in terminal instead of
*python manage.py migrate*
tape
*python3 manage.py migrate*